# How to describe AttributeMappings with object that has no key in RestKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have the json like that:

```
 {
    "response": 
    [
        8236,
        {
        "pid": 1234,
        "lat": 56,
        "long": 30,

        },
        {
        "pid": 123,
        "lat": 56,
        "long": 29
        },
    ]
}
```

So how to describe it in RKEntityMapping? How to describe object without key? What attributes should be in AttributeMappingsFromDictionary?

Do I need to create 2 classes with relationships like that:

First one will be describe Root object with variables counter and relationship to second class which have pid,lat and long?

I tried to do like described above with 2 classes and relationship but restkit crash.

Comment: You actually have an array with numbers and dictionaries? That isn't nice and you're probably out of look.

Comment: I have only one number in array and then only objects

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a response descriptor with a dynamic mapping and key path of `response`. The dynamic mapping should be passed each item in the array in turn and you can then decide what mapping to return to handle it.

To deal with the individual mapping you would need to use a nil keypath mapping.

Comment: Search for rkdynamicmapping and nil keypath mapping, there are many examples.